# " or ' in PHP but it show \" or \' in browser

Tags: php

I fill `"` or `'` at Input Text firstname and press submit, but the browser shows `\"` or `\'`. I want it to show only `"` or `'`. How I can do this?

```
<?php
    echo $_POST['firstname'];
?>
<html>
    <body>        
        <form method="post">
            <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Firstname"/>
            <input type="submit" name="ok" value="OK" />
        </form>
    </body>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) for me; Check if you have them enabled

Comment: `str_replace('\\\'', '\'', str_replace('\\"', '"', $var););` would do it, but its not the best way

Comment: thank you for help. stripslashes(); is very well for this problem

Comment: @PagornPetchara FIRST YOU ACCEPTED MY ANSWER AND THEN YOU PUTTED  IT ON YOUR ANSWER. WHY SO?

Comment: @Anant I found the easier way than your method.

Comment: @Anant I'm so sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stripslashes();` is very simple for this problem.